# Euler's infinite descent proof of sums of two squares

Tags: number-theory, proof-explanation

I started reading a book on history of algebra, after wondering how we ever got to groups, and I have been stuck on this proof ever since.

I specifically don't really understand where the contradiction lies in this proof.

Its supposed to be that you cannot have an infinite sequence of primes smaller than some $q $ that do not divide $x^2 + y^2$, by the well ordering principle of natural numbers.

However it seems to me that you couldn't have an infinite sequence of primes smaller than some $q$, even if they divided $x^2 + y^2$.

I'm not really understanding how this can be a contradiction, because you can never have an infinite descending sequence of primes, by the Well Ordering Principle.

Can anyone help me out?

The [proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_theorem_on_sums_of_two_squares#Euler%27s_proof_by_infinite_descent) is on Wikipedia (similar to the book I'm reading), and I'm going to copy the applicable bit here:

"we shall be able to find a strictly decreasing infinite sequence $ q,q_{1},q_{2},\ldots$ of positive integers which are not themselves the sums of two squares but which divide into a sum of two relatively prime squares. Since such an infinite descent is impossible, we conclude that ${\displaystyle q}$ must be expressible as a sum of two squares, as claimed."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The contradiction lies in that if no $q_i$ is produced that is the sum of two squares, then the process used to produce each $q_i$ always works. That is, there must always be a next smaller $q_{i+1}$.

It is exactly because there can not be an infinite downward sequence that this is a contradiction (prime or not, sequence of sums of squares or not, there are no infinite downward sequences of natural numbers at all). And what it contradicts is the assumption that each new $q_i$ is not a sum of two squares. Obviously one of the $q_i$ has to be a sum of two squares, and at that point the procedure for producing the next $q_{i+1}$ breaks down.